# Displaying featurelayer pulled from geodatabase using ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm working on a plugin for ArcGIS Pro that when a button is clicked, it should create a new feature layer from data pulled from a geodatabase. While it does seem to create the layer, none of the features are drawn on the map. Selecting the Attribute Table for the layer shows that the table structure is there, but no data has come over. Pictures below for a visual example.

[image: Layer shows up after clicking]

[image: Table structure, but no data.]

Below is the code used to pull the data and display it:

```
await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
        {
            Map map = MapView.Active.Map;
            CIMSqlQueryDataConnection sqldc = new CIMSqlQueryDataConnection()
            {
                //db is a variable referring to connected geodatabase.
                WorkspaceConnectionString = db.GetConnectionString(),
                GeometryType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon,
                OIDFields = "OBJECTID",
                Srid = "0",
                SqlQuery = "select * from gis.Zoning_Districts",
                Dataset = "Zoning_Districts"
            };
            try
            {
                FeatureLayer featLayer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateFeatureLayer(sqldc, map, layerName: "Zoning Districts");
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception thrown:" + e.GetType()
                    + "\n\nException: " + e, "Error Retrieving Data");
            }
        });
```

No errors seem to be thrown. Other than the layer lacking data, it seems to go correctly. Each entry in the table has a geometry column named "Shape". I do suspect I'm missing something fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, it was something fairly simple. In a couple of examples I had seen online, it was noted that if you do not know the SRID of the geometry data that you can use a value of 0. This would seem to be false.

The following can be run as a query on MS SQL to get the actual SRID:

```
select *, SHAPE.STSrid as SRID from gi.ZONING_DISTRICTS;
```

In my case, this returns a value of 102633. Plugging that into the `Srid` field of `CIMSqlQueryDataConnection()` fixed the problem and I now have my data happily displayed as a feature layer.